# AWS Codebuild projects not getting past QUEUED stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have built several codepipelines in AWS in my build environment.  Last week I had no problem building and deploying my application using these pipelines.

This week, I am unable to build/deploy anything on AWS because all of my codebuild project in these codepipelines do not complete.  They are stuck in the QUEUED stage and I must stop the codebuild projects manually.  They have run over an hour.  Even though I have cloudwatch logging setup for all of my codebuild projects, once stopped there are no logs produced.

Has anyone else experienced the issue with codebuild projects not getting out of the QUEUED stage.

All these builds worked last week but now I am unable to use any of my codepipelines because of this issue.

Comment: What image do you use for the build ?

Comment: @detzu I am using aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0

Comment: @SapphireGirl did you ever find solution to this issue?

Comment: @aksyuma  I had to get AWS Support involved.  There is a setting that a user is not able to configure.  You need to increase the QUEUES or there is a setting that AWS Support had to reset.  I had to pay for support though